# Intel CPU CONSTANTLY Throttled to Lowest Frequency - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, kernel, intel-core-i7

I am at my wits end here and could use some additional input. Long story short (more detail below), my system keeps throttling the CPU speed and I am unable to recover until I am able to unplug the battery of my laptop.

---

-> **Description of Problem**

Essentially, when all is cooperating, my CPU runs fine. I'm monitoring the CPU speed and usage with Conky and I can observe the frequency multiplier appropriately scaling based upon load. I also observe 'turbo' kick in under high load.

Then, without any discernible reason, my CPU throttles down to it's minimum of 400 MHz and remains at this level indefinitely. This includes after reboots or shutdowns - it will reboot into 400 MHz. If I push the CPU usage to 100% in this mode, it will remain at 400 MHz. I have attempted using cpufrequtils to force the CPU frequency and it does not move (`` sudo cpufreq-set -f `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq ``). Also attempted resetting the cpufrequtils service with `sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart` and the CPU remains throttled. I've now since removed cpufrequtils hoping that maybe itself was interfering with the CPU, but alas the problem remains. The only reliable method I've been able to use to recover the unit is disconnect the battery for a short period of time (1-2 minutes). As you might imagine, this is quite the pain.

Help?

---

-> ***System Info***

**Kernel:** 5.8.0-41-generic

**Distro:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

**CPU:** 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz

**Laptop Manf:** MSI

**Laptop Model:** Prestige 15 A11SCX-002

---

-> **Output of 'cpupower frequency-info'**

```
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: intel_pstate
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.80 GHz
available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.80 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
current CPU frequency: 1.60 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

---

Notes:

(1) I've tried adjusting the governor to performance to no avail - it does not appear to matter regarding the throttling.

(2) I cannot determine a reliable method to reproduce the issue. Sometimes it will throttle 10 minutes after initial boot or 3 hours after initial boot.

(3) I've tried various kernel versions (5.4 & 5.10 namely) and the issue persists.

(4) I've also tried adjusting the CPU driver by disabling via grub with `intel_pstate=disable` added to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` env variable. This forces my kernel to default to the *acpi-cpufreq* driver (confirmed with cpupower). Still the issue persists.

(5) Fast boot is disabled and I have no indications via BIOS that the BIOS is throttling my CPU as well.

Comment: Update: The CPU does not appear to get above 45C, however. I wonder if thermald is throttling?

Comment: Update: lm-sensors does not detect any fans. When I stress the cpu the core voltage goes from ~1.2V to ~0.6V and I do not physically observe any change in fan speed. I am thinking the kernel is unable to modulate the laptop cooling fan and perhaps this is where the throttling is coming from?

Comment: Cross-posted as [Intel CPU CONSTANTLY Throttled to Lowest Frequency - Ubuntu 20.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632339) on https://linux.stackexchange.com/.  Probably this site is the best place for it, so the others should be deleted.  (Cross-posting is not generally allowed on StackExchange sites, unless your question is closed as off-topic like [the original on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66016899))